# C# async stream read/write adds unexpected values in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, asynchronous

I have written a web client that used sync calls for writing to the stream

```
void WriteBytes(WebRequest request, IntPtr ptr, int length)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, length);
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

After transitioning to async calls:

```
Stream requestStreamAsync = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
await requestStreamAsync.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

And in addition all other relevant sync calls were changed to async,

The buffers received on the server end are filled with unexpected values when running in Debug mode with breakpoints.
If I run without breakpoints everything works fine.

I'm running VS2012, Windows Server 2012 with .NET 4.5.1

Any ideas?

Comment: I *suspect* you've got other threads replacing the contents of `bytes` while you're writing. It's hard to tell just from that tiny bit of code though - please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Be careful with words like `garbage` when talking about c#. You could get crosstalk with _garbage collection_ in your answers. Instead, try explicit descriptions like `unexpected values` or `corrupted data`. I came here expecting a memory problem.

Comment: Adding breakpoints does of course alter the timing of a program. It is for example possible that they cause time-outs to happen. So what is your actual problem?

Comment: The program is rather complicated, as the `Write` method I'm calling is actually being called from C++. The issue could not be with the contents of bytes because it is a local buffer

Comment: In addition, it works without any breakpoints

Comment: Dangling pointers is a very common hazard in native code.  High odds that this IntPtr just doesn't point to valid memory anymore once you use async and use the pointer later.